# django multiple search terms

Tags: python, html, django

I want to add all the columns in 1 algorithm for a search. If it is possible.

Something like this:

***UPDATE *** ( i have update the views.py and search_table.html )
It is only searching correctly the url field. The id and the title anything i put in those fields it will give me the entire table.

***views.py***

def search_table(request, pk):
    table_name = Crawledtables.objects.get(id=pk)
    t = create_model(table_name.name)

```
q = request.GET['q']
if q is not None:

    query = t.objects.filter(Q(id__icontains=q) | Q(title__icontains=q) | Q(url__icontains=q))
    return render(request, 'search/results_table.html', {'tbl_name': table_name,
                                                         'details': query,
                                                         'query': q})

else:
    return HttpResponse("Please submit a search term!")
```

***results_table.html***

```
<strong> {{ tbl_name }}</strong>
    <p> You searched for: <strong>{{ query }}</strong></p>
    {% if details %}
        <p> Found {{ details|length }}</p>
    <div class="row">

        <table class="table table-bordered sortable">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Url</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
                    <tbody>
            {% for lists in details %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ lists.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ lists.title }}</td>
                    <td><a href="{{ lists.url }}" target="_blank">{{ lists.url }}</a></td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>

    {% else %}
        <p> No results found</p>
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

***search_table.html***

```
{% if tbl_name %}
    <form action="/search/{{ tbl_name.id }}/results" method="GET">
{% endif %}
<input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Id">
<input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Title">
<input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Url">
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
```

***UPDATE***

*models.py*

```
def create_model(db_table):
    class CustomMetaClass(ModelBase):
        def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
            model = super(CustomMetaClass, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
            model._meta.db_table = db_table
            return model

    class AllTables(models.Model):
        __metaclass__ = CustomMetaClass

        id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
        title = models.CharField(db_column='Title', blank=True, null=True, max_length=250)
        url = models.CharField(db_column='Url', unique=True, max_length=250, blank=True,
                               null=True)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Created_at')

    return AllTables
```

Comment: Do you want to use the one search term on each field (with OR logic) or a specific search term for each field?

Comment: specific search term for each field

Answer (score 1):

#### Q objects are used to make complex logical queries.

use in syntax: AND (&) and OR  (|)

```
from django.db.models import Q


t.objects.filter(Q(id__icontains=q_id) | Q(title__icontains=q_title) | Q(url__icontains=q_url))
```

Comment: thank you...but how do i do the if statement for it? do i leave it the same? or name all of them '*q*' ?

Comment: @Omega, you can use single input field for all three, id, title and url.. if you just want to match with any of the columns.

Please accept the answer. if you are satisfied with it

Comment: I have update the question with the new changes. Because it is not searching every field...only the url

Comment: i posted the model

Comment: I am sorry.. I was looking for "t" model.

Comment: i will change it to the AllTables model which is the "t"

Comment: i have changed it